# How to differentiate between System Audio and Microphone Audio in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, electron, navigator

I'm developing an electron app with react. I have a functionality in which I want to record audio for both microphone and system and send them to backend in different variables.

For that, I have used the Navigator object from JS, but it is giving me combined audio of microphone and system. I want to save them differently in different variables.

For example:

```
const microphoneAudio = [microphone audio]
const systemAudio = [system audio]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find how to differentiate system audio and microphone audio.Hope it will help you!

```
function recordSystemAudio() {
    navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
            audio: { echoCancellation: true },
        })
        .then((stream) => {
            // Handle the stream

            const audioContext = new AudioContext();
            const source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
            const destination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();

            source.connect(destination);

            const tabStream = destination.stream;

            let tabMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(tabStream);

            console.log('tabstream', {
                audioContext,
                source,
                destination,
                tabStream,
                tabMediaRecorder,
            });

            window.systemAudio = tabMediaRecorder;

            const chunks = [];

            tabMediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
                chunks.push(event.data);

                const audioBlob = new Blob(chunks);
                const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
                const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);

                console.log({ audioBlob, audioUrl, audio }, 'Event Data');
                const audioFile = new File([audioBlob], 'audio.wav', {
                    type: 'audio/wav',
                });

                // console.log('audioFile', audioFile);
                sendAudioToAPI(audioFile);
            });

            tabMediaRecorder.start(2000);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Handle the error
        });
}


const microPhoneAudio = async () => {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
    });
    // Call the captureSystemAudio function to capture the system audio
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    window.microPhoneAudio = mediaRecorder;
    mediaRecorder.start(2000);
    const audioChunks = [];
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
        audioChunks.push(event.data);
        const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);
        const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
        const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
        const audioFile = new File([audioBlob], 'audio.wav', {
            type: 'audio/wav',
        });
        console.log('audioFile', audioFile);
        sendMicrophoneAudioToAPI(audioFile);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then(devices => {
    const microphones = devices.filter(device => device.kind === 'audioinput' && device.label.includes('Built-in'));

  .catch(error => {
    // Handle errors here
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but I've already tried this, and it's not really working. I am getting different output and input devices by this, but I am unable to store the audio by them separately

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use multiple microphones at the same time to record audio and then store it separately

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: { deviceId: { exact: mic1Id } } })
  .then(stream1 => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: { deviceId: { exact: mic2Id } } })
      .then(stream2 => {
        const context = new AudioContext();
        const source1 = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream1);
        const source2 = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream2);
        const destination1 = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
        const destination2 = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
        source1.connect(destination1);
        source2.connect(destination2);
        const recorder1 = new MediaRecorder(destination1.stream);
        const recorder2 = new MediaRecorder(destination2.stream);
        recorder1.start();
        recorder2.start();
      });
  });
```